# Md-datepicker don't work Firefox ESR 38

Tags: angularjs, firefox, angular-material

I use Angular Material with md-datepicker in my app.
My app has to work on Firefox ESR 38 and 45.
md-datepicker works well with Firefox ESR 45 but not with version ESR 38.
I have Angular Material 1.1.4 and AngularJS 1.5.9.
When I click on datepicher, the calender show but I can't select on the date.
No error on console.